# Identifying zero force members

Tags: statics

My instructor said that if a joint has reaction support attached to it, then it is not a zero force member. However I saw in this figure that joints E and A are attached to a pin and a roller, respectively but it is indicated in the answer key that members DE and AE are zero force members. What is your insight about this?

[image]

source: Engineering Mechanics - Statics (R. C. Hibbeler)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to simplify a truss bridge diagram?](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/42371/how-to-simplify-a-truss-bridge-diagram)

Answer (score 3):

DE and AE are zero are indeed zero.

However you need to start from  point C to reason about that.

If you look at [this question](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/42371/how-to-simplify-a-truss-bridge-diagram/42374#42374), when you have a node without external forces with **only** two members which are not colinear, the forces on the nodes should be zero. So from this $DC$ and $CB$ are equal to zero.

### **Node D:**

Now if you take point D and write the equations of equilibrium you obtain:

- for x
  $$  ED - DC =0 \rightarrow $$
  $$  ED = DC =0 $$
- for y: (so all the force is carried from ED
  $$  -DB - 3kN =0 \rightarrow $$
  $$  DB = - 3kN $$

### **Node A:**

Again for Node A if you take the equilibrium in the y-axis you get:

$$  +AE =0 $$

because A has rolling support and it produces only a horizontal reaction.

Answer (score 3):

Use graphics to visualize the force flow and determine zero-force members. (Draw member forces from joint D)

[image]